# Is there a desktop note taking software connected to Google Keep?

Tags: software-recommendation, google

For the convenience of managing note and todo items on mobile, and the Google Voice integration, I use Google Keep.

I hope there is a desktop Ubuntu software which allows me to access my Google Keep notes.

Answer (score 16):

You can check out this article at [Install Google Keep in Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty | UbuntuHandbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-google-keep-in-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/)

> 1. Download the Google Chrome web browser at: [Google Chrome Web Browser](https://chrome.google.com)
>
>    You may check out your OS type (32 or 64 bit) via System *Settings →Details→Overview*.
> 2. Install the package via Ubuntu Software Center, or by running the below command in terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal):
>
>    ```
>    sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_*.deb && sudo apt-get -f install
>    ```
> 3. Open Chrome browser and go to [Google Keep for Chrome page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-notes-and-lis/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki?hl=en).
>
>    Click on the blue button which says "Free" and then select add to Chrome.
> 4. Once you installed this app, type in `chrome://apps/` in address bar to go to the Chrome Apps page.
>
>    There you’ll see a list of app shortcuts including Google Keep. Right-click on the icon and select "Create Shortcuts…"
>
>    [image]
> 5. Right click and create a shortcut to your desktop
>
>    [image]

Comment: FYI: this whole process can be done in Chromium, which is the open-source base of Chrome, and is available from Ubuntu repos, no need to download anything.

Comment: Things have changed in Chrome. Keep now appears as an extension. How do we add the shortcut in Chrome version 81?

Comment: @vineeshvs app is still available.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-notes-and-lis/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki?hl=en

I just did the process on Ubuntu 20.04 with Chrome v83, worked for me.

Comment: @user3601262 Thanks. It worked for me. Now I have the desktop shortcut for Google keep in Ubuntu 16.04. Note-taking has become 10x easier across devices for me.

Comment: Nice and concise answer!!...Elementary O.S. thanks

Comment: And now, as for 2021 Google Keep app is absolete...