# Is there any way to use Google Keep in Ubuntu in 2022, now that Chrome apps are being phased out?

Tags: software-recommendation, google

I came across this question about Google Keep. The existing answer is no longer relevant, since Chrome apps are being [phased out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104622/is-there-a-desktop-note-taking-software-connected-to-google-keep#comment2304458_1104641).

How to use Google Keep with Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: *Any* way? Just open it in a browser.

Comment: @muru Good idea. Can be easily done with something like this https://itsfoss.com/web-app-manager-linux-mint/ (it can be installed in Ubuntu).

Comment: @muru Would you like to write that as a proper answer?

Comment: I didn't read the comments while I was writing the answer. This is a rough and ready answer. I will be happy if muru writes a better version.

Comment: I haven't seen anything about Chrome Apps or the Chrome Store being phased out.  I have no idea where that comment came from as the person didn't post anything backing up their claim about it. There was some stuff back in June of this year, but as far as I know they stated that it would be supported at least until 2025. I cannot see anything on their pages about it being phased out in the near future.  And I very highly doubt that they will since they use their apps also on their own corporate side.  I think you're safe.

Comment: @Terrance Also see https://askubuntu.com/a/1445654/124466. More than one person said that the solution in that answer is not working

Comment: I right-clicked my Chrome apps and it made desktop shortcuts to them.  I am running 22.04.  So I am not seeing what you are seeing.  Of course, I have never seen Keep in the chrome://apps page, I have always just gone to keep.google.com, or used the Android app on it.

Comment: And I actually just added Keep to the Chrome apps through https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-notes-and-lis/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki/related?hl=en and I was able to right-click it and add it to my applications menu very easily.  However, it did make me update it, but that took mere seconds to do.

Comment: @muru's right, and I can confirm it works very nicely in Firefox in a pinned tab (I prefer to clutter my tab bar rather than my XFCE panel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer shows how to use Google Keep as a standalone web app in the browser (Chrome/Chromium/Firefox).

---

### Google Chrome/Chromium

---

## Try it in the terminal

There is a command line `-app=` option you can try. Open a terminal and enter

```
google-chrome -app=https://keep.google.com
```

This will open the Keep web page without tabs, the address box, menu, toolbar, or the installed chrome extension icons.

It looks pretty much like a desktop Google Keep app. If you like this approach, follow the next steps.

## Create a desktop launcher

Create a desktop launcher file in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` folder with the following text.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Google Keep
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome -app=https://keep.google.com
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=google-chrome
Type=Application
```

I have kept the Chrome icon above. You may want to change to something more suitable.

Name this file `keep.desktop` and save it.

Now you should have a searchable desktop app for Keep.

## The GUI way using Chrome

1. Open https://keep.google.com in Google chrome
2. Click on the three vertical dot menu on the top right corner
3. Click on More `Tools > Create Shortcut...`.
4. Check the box **Open as Window** and then the button <kbd>Create</kbd>.

That is pretty much it.

Hope this helps

### Firefox

---

First, install Linux Mint Webapp Manager in Ubuntu.

```
wget http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/w/webapp-manager/webapp-manager_1.2.8_all.deb
sudo apt install ./webapp-manager_1.2.8_all.deb
```

Now open Webapp Manager, and click on the add button.
[image: webapp manager]

Now, add information about Google Keep.
[image]
(The icon is named `chrome-google-keep` in the Papirus Icon theme. In case you don't have this icon theme, you can manually download the icon from internet and add it)

Now, Google Keep should show up among your apps.

Comment: The `-app=https://keep.google.com` command-line switch works with Brave as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found any official word from Google (I have my sources internally) that the Google Apps and/or the Chrome Store are being phased out (yet).  So, for now the answer that was linked originally is still working fine as long as you do with with the Chrome (possibly Chromium but I don't have it installed) browser.  The other answer here is great for the other steps like command line to do and also allowing you to create web apps with Firefox (which is pretty cool).

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 108.0.5359.124
```

1. Open https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-notes-and-lis/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki/related?hl=en in Chrome to add Keep as a Chrome App to Chrome browser.

   [image]
2. While in Chrome goto `chrome://apps`.  Right-click on `Keep` and choose *Create Shortcuts*

   [image]
3. Choose both Desktop and Applications Menu, if you want both.

   [image]
4. Desktop and Applications Menu shortcuts should be created.

   [image]

   [image]
5. Enjoy Google Keep as a web app.

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS running Google Chrome 112.0.5615.49 (64-bits) you can follow these steps:

1. in Chrome, start [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com/) (https://keep.google.com/)
2. in the 3 dots menu (top right, underneath the minimize|maximize|close window-buttons, select "Install Google Keep" (the line under 'Find... (Ctrl + F)'
3. Done, you can find Google Keep now in your sofware apps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).